# Hadoop Hive DOUBLE type question

Tags: hadoop, hive

Quick Hive/Hadoop question from a new user.

I have a DOUBLE column that has "1.8E8" for value, does it mean I reached the max value for DOUBLE?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `1.8e8` is tiny. The maximum value for a IEEE 754 double is about `2.22e308`.

Comment: So it means my value is too big for the window I'm looking at but that it's intact in the database and I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: To me it appears that you have 1.8e8 in the database. Do you know otherwise?

Comment: I'll admit I suck at math but if my hive column is a double, then the value can't be a "1.8e8" string, so 1.8e8 has to be the representation of a number, right?

Comment: All I'm saying is - how do you 1.8e8 is not the right value? It's not possible to tell at this point if this is a formatting problem or if it's incorrectly stored. Can you supply more detail about the things you've tried (preferably with code)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is the representation of decimal value in Hive.

1.8E8 --> 180000000

Refer this link for more details:

http://www.aptibook.com/discuss-technical?uid=tech-hive12&question=Double-type-in-Hive-%E2%80%93-Important-points